# How to show $p_n$ $\leq$ $2^{2^n}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Let $p_n$ be the $n_{th}$ prime (e.g. $p_1 = 2$; $p_2 = 3$; $p_3 = 5$). Show that $p_n \leq 2^{2^n}$ for all $n$.

I don't see how I can approximate the value of $p_n$. Do I need something like prime number theorem? But the course didn't even teach that yet.

Comment: You could use the fact that if $p_1,\ldots,p_n$ are the first $n$ primes, then the $(n+1)$st prime is less than or equal to $p_1\cdots p_n + 1$ (Euclid's argument for the infinitude of primes). So, inductively, $p_{n+1}\leq 2^{2^1}\times\cdots\times 2^{2^n}+1 = 2^{2^1+\cdots+2^n}+1$.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that this is an *incredibly* crude bound. The prime number theorem states that $p_n$ is in fact approximately $n \log n \ll n^2 \ll 2^n \ll 2^{2^n}$.

Comment: @Arturo: Typing my answer took longer than you typing you comment, but the idea is of course exactly the same as yours.

Comment: @Thijs: Indeed; which is why I upvoted your answer. (-:

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The idea is that you use induction, and that you expand on Euclid's argument that there are infinitely many primes to show that $p_n$ is bounded above by $2^{2^n}$.

Suppose $p_i \leq 2^{2^i}$ for all $i \leq n$. Now $p_1 \cdot p_2 \cdot \ldots \cdot p_n + 1$ is not divisible by any of the primes $p_1, \ldots, p_n$, so

$$p_{n+1} \leq \prod_{i=1}^n \ p_i + 1$$

Substituting the earlier bounds on $p_i$ and using $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^i = 2^{n+1} - 2$, we get

$$p_{n+1} \leq \left(\prod_{i=1}^n \ 2^{2^i}\right) + 1 = \left(2^{\sum_{i=1}^n 2^i}\right) + 1 = 2^{2^{n+1} - 2} + 1 \leq 2^{2^{n+1}}$$

Answer (score 19):

It is enough to prove that for any positive integer $n$, there are at least $n$ primes that are $\le 2^{2^n}$. We will show that in fact $2^{2^n}-1$ always has at least $n$ distinct prime divisors. (All of these are necessarily $<2^{2^n}$.)

Suppose we know that $2^{2^k}-1$ has at least $k$ distinct prime divisors.  Then we must show that $2^{2^{k+1}}-1$ has at least $k+1$ distinct prime divisors.

Note that
$$2^{2^{k+1}}-1=(2^{2^k}-1)(2^{2^k}+1).$$
The numbers $2^{2^k}-1$ and $2^{2^k}+1$ are relatively prime.  This is because any number that divides both of them must divide their difference, which is $2$.  But each of 
$2^{2^k}-1$ and $2^{2^k}+1$ is odd, so the greatest integer that divides both of them cannot be $2$, and therefore must be $1$.

Thus the prime divisors of $2^{2^{k+1}}-1$ are the prime divisors of $2^{2^k}-1$ (of which there are at least $k$), together with the prime divisors of $2^{2^k}+1$ (of which there is at least $1$), for a total of at least $k+1$.

**Comment**: The above argument also tells us that for any positive integer $n$, there are at least $n$ primes.  This gives us a proof of the infinitude of the primes which is a little different from the usual "Euclid" proof.

Comment: (+1): very nice example how to make things simple - I think, the "least effort solution" :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here we look at a smaller, and as I feel, more convenient bound:

Assume each prime would be the double of the previous, we had, beginning with the first prime *q=2* the sequence $ \small q, 2q, 4q, 8q, \ldots 2^n q , \ldots...$ and the *n*'th prime were bounded by $ \small q2^n $ which is much smaller than the given $ \small 2^{2^n} $ . Now if we recall  that **between** *n* and *2n* there is always a prime, thus the distance to the next is even smaller than *n* , then this is sufficient for the proof in general and we need only look at the initial cases for possible exceptions.

Comment: @Gottfried: The question seems more aimed at getting the student familiar with proof techniques (induction) than proving a sharp bound on the size of the $n$th prime. But indeed, one can improve the bound quite a bit ;-)

Comment: @Thijs: Well, I was thinking just in that path of an exercise for proofs (and Bertrand's postulate seemed to me to be *the* elementary knowledge here). But possibly I'm too far away from the actual courses to have an appropriate intuition. So if I was obfuscating here, I'll apologize to the OP...